# How to put initial parameters into applet?

Tags: java, applet

How to put into applet initial parameters without using this:

```
<param name="foo" value="bar"></param>
```

I don't want to use code written above, because applet must be used with big initial paramter: two arrays of Strings. Each array can contain up to 50 string elements.  So i think it's bad to write this parameters into HTML page as:

```
 <param name="foo1" value="GUID #1"></param>
 <param name="foo2" value="GUID #2"></param>
 .....
 <param name="foo90" value="GUID #90"></param>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Use just one parameter key and concatenate the values separated by commas, so you get something like:

   ```
   <param name="foo" value="GUID #1,GUID #2,GUID #3,....,GUID #90"></param>
   ```

   Then you split the value by commas in the applet code.
2. Read the parameters from an external file. This is slightly more difficult because you have to create a `URLConnection` to read the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using just pure HTML, (i.e. using PHP, JSP or ASP etc.)
why don't you generate them via loops? For example, PHP version could be like that:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++)
    echo ("<param name='foo" + $i + "1' value='GUID " + $i + "'></param>");
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
  PARAM NAME="myArray" VALUE="element1 element2 ... elementN"
```